# cls on a Get-Content -Wait call.

Tags: powershell

Is it possible (if so how) to clear my screen (`cls`) when my command 
    `Get-Content -Path [path location] -Tail 1 -wait`
sees that the file has been modified before printing the change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think Get-Content has this functionality but it shouldn't be hard to implement manually. Example:

```
$old = $null
while ($true) {
    $new = Get-Content -Path $path -Tail 1
    if ($new -ne $old) {
        Clear-Host 
        Write-Host $new
        $old = $new
    }
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}
```

To output all added lines:

```
$old = [String]::Empty
while ($true) {
    $new = Get-Content -Path $path
    if ($new.Count -ne $old.Count) {
        Clear-Host 
        Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $old -DifferenceObject $new `
            | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "InputObject"
        $old = $new
    }
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}
```

Comment: It did solve my issue but is there a way for me to show all new lines added not just the last one.

Comment: You could use `Compare-Object`. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you. This is my first adventure into Powershell.